# Need help in creating ssis package task to export csv from sql table to sub folders in main folder

Tags: ssis

Used foreachloopcontainer and file system task to create sub folders in main folders

used data flow task and creating dynamically csv file

i need to loop through each sub folder and create csv file

could you please help

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Save the filename and Folder path in a `variable`. Create a flat file connection. In the `properties` tab, dynamically define the `ConnectionString` using `Expressions`.

Comment: I cannot create folder path as variable as these folders are generated dynamically in above step in for each loop container

Comment: How do you get the path to create the folder you want?

Comment: I am storing in one object variable for values i get as output for execute sql task

Comment: OK. So, by using `foreach loop`, you have saved the file path in a `variable`. Place `Data Flow Task` inside `foreach loop` after `file system task`.